# How can I enable Quirks Mode on MacOS?

Tags: macos, web, internet-explorer, software-design, quirks-mode

I'm using a cloud software product that has an old Quirks Mode that I need access to on my Mac but not all the pages load in the right way when using Chrome or other browsers like Microsoft Edge.

Do you know a workaround for this so I can use Quirks mode on my Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this extension where I can run internet explorer on your mac inside chrome: https://www.ietab.net/